# Strange readings when connecting an FSR to Pi using MCP3008

Tags: gpio, sensor, analog-to-digital

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hJXF.jpg)I have connected a square Adafruit Force Sensitive Resistor 406 up to a Raspberry Pi following the instructions given here: [Using an FSR with a Raspberry Pi](https://acaird.github.io/computers/2015/01/07/raspberry-pi-fsr)

I have wired everything up exactly as mentioned and used the code linked in the text.[[image: Wiring Config]]

However when I run the program the reading from the FSR is either 2047 or 0. It seems to make no difference whether I apply any force to the sensor.

I am wondering if you can give me advice on what could be causing this problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Something is wired incorrectly.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have tried wiring direct to the pins and also via the breadboard but the same result each time. Could it be a possibility that the MCP3008 is faulty? I will need to buy a new analog component to test if this is the case

Comment: Yes,that is possible.  Incorrect wiring is more likely.  Have you wired without the cobbler?  People connect the ribbon cable the wrong way around.  You need to post a photo of your connections.

Comment: I am pretty certain it is all wired up correctly, as I have tried with and without the cobbler. I have attached a picture of my wiring. Under the ribbon cable is a connection from the 3v3 to the live rail.

Comment: You need to show the **actual** text of the script you are using.   Most people would use the dedicated SPI GPIO rather than bit-bang (the scripts pointed to are ancient in Pi terms).

Comment: @joan finally got around to testing it with another sensor and you are right, the code is outdated. Will place the working code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code I copied from the linked pages is redundant. The most simple way of getting a reading using the MCP3008 with the FSR connected as illustrated above is as follows:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008
from time import sleep
read = MCP3008(channel=0, device=0)

while True:
    readingVolts = read.value * 1000
    print(readingVolts)
    sleep(2)
```